# How to place object in Inventor drawing using custom UCS

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, autodesk-inventor

My Inventor model somehow ended up with its coordinate system very misaligned with its faces so that when I try to create a drawing, the orthographic projections I get aren't the best (the top right one is the 'isometric' view):
[image]

I created a new custom UCS in the model so that the front, top, and side views I get from it look good. But how do I place the model view in the drawing file using the UCS as the default coordinate system?

Comment: I solved my _problem_ : I reset the view cube's "top" and "front" orientations by rotating it to the correct ones, right clicking the cube, and selecting "Set Current view as". But I'll let this stay up because there might be someone who needs the answer to it specifically.

Comment: Write an answer to it yourself.  That will allow it to conclude correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem : I reset the view cube's "top" and "front" orientations by rotating it to the correct ones, right clicking the cube, and selecting "Set Current view as".